# file writing permission error as user www-data

Tags: php, python, permissions

I am trying to write to a file by running a python script as user www-data. When I run the script using the following:

```
sudo python my_script.py
```

it writes fine. When I run the PHP script as www-data it doesn't write. Permissions:

```
folder(PiControl....contains status_log file): drwxrwxrwx
file(status_log....the file I am trying to write to): -rwxrwxrwx User:www-data group:www-data
```

writing to file Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime

status="on"

with open("status_log", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("{} {} {}".format("<br>light is now:", status,datetime.datetime.now()))
```

I created a webpage button to run the file

Can someone tell me what to change here?

Comment: does www-data have access to ALL of the folders above wherever the file is? having the file and its immediate parent be writeable is irrelevant if the grandparent or great-grandparent are still locked down.

Comment: I have a symlink from a folder on my desktop to my www/ directory to serve webpages. Does the path from the folder on my desktop need to be allowed or the path from the actual www/ folder?

Comment: Can you post the parts of both scripts that write the file?

Comment: symlinks can't bypass permissions. the www-data user will need to have access to your home directory, which is something you really shouldn't be doing... www-data should be a minimum-necessary privs account. giving it access to other things on the system is a BAD idea.

Comment: Yes, I realize this is HIGHLY insecure.....Im just messing around with Python and a raspberry pi

Comment: @MarcB, To answer your question the permissions on the directory home are also set to chmod 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had symlink'ed my web files from my home directory when the PHP read status_log they found it in my local directory, when www-data wrote to it (via the Python above) it created the file in /var/www, instead of /home where I was trying to read it from.

The solution was to change the path of the file being read to its location in: /var/www